# Fit the map view of an Image Overlay to the size of the container Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using React Leaflet to create a custom map.

The card (Image Overlay) is currently being rendered, but it does not fill the container in which the card is placed.

The size of the container is set strictly and I would like the map to fill the container as much as possible. All attempts to resize with CSS failed.

Live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-worker-8qbzfr

My code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { MapContainer, ImageOverlay } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";

const M = ({ width, height, zoom, center }) => {
  const wh = [width, 500];
  const origin = [0, 0];
  const bounds = [origin, wh];

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "1100px", height: "600px" }}>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "100%", minHeight: "100%" }}
        bounds={zoom ? undefined : bounds}
        boundsOptions={{
          padding: [0, 0]
        }}
        maxBounds={bounds}
        zoom={center ? zoom : undefined}
        center={zoom ? center : undefined}
      >
        <ImageOverlay
          url="../ptichnikDraw.png"
          bounds={bounds}
          className="map_main"
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      <M width={1500} height={500} center={[0, 0]} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your "card" (the `<ImageOverlay>`) to fill the initial map container/viewport.

You will not be able to do so using (only) CSS, but with Leaflet map options and methods, which are exposed by React Leaflet wrapper:

1. Use the Leaflet map [`whenReady`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-whenready) option (exposed as a prop of [`<MapContainer>`](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/api-map/#mapcontainer)) to attach a callback that is executed once the map is initialized

> Runs the given function `fn` when the map gets initialized

2. While not explicitly documented, that callback receives a [load](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-load) event argument, which [`target`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-target) property is the newly instantiated Leaflet map

> Fired when the map is initialized

3. Call the [`fitBounds()`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-fitbounds) map method on that instance, with the same bounds as your Image Overlay, to have the map view be adjusted accordingly

> Sets a map view that contains the given geographical bounds with the maximum zoom level possible.

4. **Important:** make sure to set the map [`zoomSnap`](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomsnap) option to value `0`, otherwise the fitBounds will be modified so that the final zoom is a multiple of `zoomSnap` (default to 1, i.e. integer zoom levels)

> Forces the map's zoom level to always be a multiple of this, particularly right after a `fitBounds()` or a pinch-zoom. By default, the zoom level snaps to the nearest integer; lower values (e.g. `0.5` or `0.1`) allow for greater granularity. A value of `0` means the zoom level will not be snapped after `fitBounds` or a pinch-zoom.

```
const M = ({ width, height, zoom, center }) => {
  const wh = [width, 500];
  const origin = [0, 0];
  const bounds = [origin, wh];

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "1100px", height: "600px" }}>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "100%", minHeight: "100%" }}
        bounds={zoom ? undefined : bounds}
        boundsOptions={{
          padding: [0, 0]
        }}
        maxBounds={bounds}
        zoom={center ? zoom : undefined}
        center={zoom ? center : undefined}
        zoomSnap={0} // Important to disable snap after fitBounds
        whenReady={(e) => e.target.fitBounds(bounds)} // Have the map adjust its view to the same bounds as the Image Overlay
      >
        <ImageOverlay
          url="../ptichnikDraw.png"
          bounds={bounds}
          className="map_main"
        />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Updated CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-tree-lz1o9q

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation! Your help is truly invaluable!

Comment: Dear, ghybs. You helped me so much with the map that I would like to contact you again. Now I'm trying to place a marker on the map, but I can't determine its exact coordinates in any way.

Comment: When I set the value of 100 on the Y-axis, the marker is located at the upper border, but if I set the value of 50 for the Y-axis, then it is not at all in the middle of the map. The same is true for the X-axis. I would be very grateful if you help me! I added a new component in project https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-worker-8qbzfr?file=/src/Marker.jsx called Marker. It has a position property that determines the position of the marker.

Comment: Please feel free to open a new question with these details and code.

Comment: Created a new question on the positioning of the marker on the map. I hope for your help. Thanks =) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75280947/marker-position-on-the-map-leaflet

Answer (score 0):

Using the default Leaflet JavaScript library you can use map.invalidateSize(). Don't know how that would work in React but maybe you can figure that one out using the documentation.