# Marker position on the map Leaflet

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have a custom map created using the Leaflet library. And also the Marker component. When I place a marker with a value of 100 on the Y-axis, the marker is at the top of the map, but when I place a marker on the Y-axis of 50, the marker is not in the middle of the map. Same thing with the X-axis. How can I find the exact coordinates of the map, what can I do to position the marker according to the coordinates passed from the backend?

Code from component App

```
import "./styles.css";
import { MapContainer, ImageOverlay } from "react-leaflet";
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import Marker from "./Marker";

const M = ({ width, height, zoom, center }) => {
  const wh = [width, 500];
  const origin = [0, 0];
  const bounds = [origin, wh];

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "1100px", height: "600px" }}>
      <MapContainer
        style={{ height: "100%", minHeight: "100%" }}
        bounds={zoom ? undefined : bounds}
        boundsOptions={{
          padding: [0, 0]
        }}
        maxBounds={bounds}
        zoom={center ? zoom : undefined}
        center={zoom ? center : undefined}
      >
        <ImageOverlay
          url="../ptichnikDraw.png"
          bounds={bounds}
          className="map_main"
        />
        <Marker />
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      <M width={1500} height={500} center={[0, 0]} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Code from component Marker

```
import { LeafletTrackingMarker } from "react-leaflet-tracking-marker";
import L from "leaflet";
import { Popup } from "react-leaflet";

const icon = L.icon({
  iconSize: [35, 35],
  popupAnchor: [2, -20],
  iconUrl: require("../public/marker_map.png")
});

export default function Marker() {
  return (
    <>
      <LeafletTrackingMarker
        icon={icon}
        position={[50, 450]} // changing the position of the marker
        duration={10}
      ></LeafletTrackingMarker>
    </>
  );
}
```

Link to full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-worker-8qbzfr?file=/src/Marker.jsx

Comment: Start by reading https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html

Comment: As pointed out by IvanSanchez in the previous question comment, make sure to use `L.CRS.Simple` in your case (see the mentioned link for explanations) https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-cori-z6r228?file=/src/App.js